# Will calling google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween contribute to my API limit?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need to call the computeDistanceBetween method about 30,000 times, and I'm concerned it will cause me to exceed my Google API limit. Does this method contribute to the limit, or am I safe to use it as many times as I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As that function is part of the Javascript API, it looks like a recent change would cause those method calls to contribute to the limit.

> As of June 22, 2016 we are making the following changes to the Google Maps APIs Standard Plan:
>   ...
>   We now count Google Maps JavaScript API client-side requests towards the daily limit of the associated web service API.*

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/

Comment: Bummer, looks like I just missed out. For anyone else in my situation, I recommend they google the Haversine function - there are plenty of functions out there that will mimic computeDistanceBetween() without the need for the google API